# Error showing alert while comparing dates

Tags: android

I am new in android try to add some of birth dates of user contact, and comparing these dates stored in database with current date of system,below is my code, it successfully store data but, then showing some problem in alert dialog part, alert is not working, can anybody help

public class start extends Activity {

```
// Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
ImageView i1, i2;
entry entry;
String date[];
String name[];
String cono[];

String month[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
int num[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.forget.R.layout.start);

    final Context context = this;
    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.forget.R.id.imageView1);
    i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.forget.R.id.imageView2);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, show.class);

    String da = getDate();
    System.out.println(da);

    // get data by Dob
    entry = new entry(context);

    List<Event> event = entry.getdatabByDate(da);

    Iterator li = event.iterator();

    String dateev = "";
    String nameev = "";
    String conodob = "";
    while (li.hasNext()) {
        Event event2 = (Event) li.next();
        dateev = event2.getDob() + "/" + dateev;
        conodob = event2.getContact() + "/" + conodob;
        nameev = event2.getName() + "/" + nameev;
    }

    date = dateev.split("/");
    name = nameev.split("/");
    cono = conodob.split("/");

    for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
        if (date[i].equals(da)) {
            final String n = name[i];
            final String con = cono[i];
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            ab.setTitle("Your Title");
            ab.setMessage("Today " + n + " Birthday")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                        int arg1) {

                                    sendSms(con);

                                }
                            })

                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "NO", 4000).show();

                                }
                            });

            AlertDialog ab1 = ab.create();
            ab1.show();

        }
    }

    i1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    i2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
}

public void sendSms(String conoOfDob) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), conoOfDob, 4000).show();

    /*
     * PendingIntent
     * pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivities(getApplicationContext(), 0,
     * null, 0); SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
     * sms.sendTextMessage(conoOfDob, null, "Happy Bday", pendingIntent,
     * null);
     */

}

public void SendSms(String conoOfDob) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), conoOfDob, 4000).show();

    /*
     * PendingIntent
     * pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivities(getApplicationContext(), 0,
     * null, 0); SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
     * sms.sendTextMessage(conoOfDob, null, "Happy Bday", pendingIntent,
     * null);
     */

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public String getDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
    String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, 2000).show();

    return strDate;

}
```

}

Comment: if you have an error post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/) for create simple alertdiaglog box. Check this out and post the error log so that we know, what goes wrong in your code.